# What is a good security framework or API?

Tags: java, security, frameworks

Is there a framework to be used when you build an application with security? (Preferably in Java.)

Comment: Are you talking about security like encryption, or do you mean like authentication?

Comment: if you need your application "to be secure", there's no generic framework that you can just slap on and be done. if you have specific requirements around encryption, digital signatures, authentication, authorization, etc. you should list what your requirements are, as multiple frameworks can provide better support for each of these.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spring Security - http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/ - offers pretty much everything you can think of and works perfectly if you're already using Spring for [IOC (inversion of control)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).

Comment: but also too much complicated.

Comment: @Raj I tend to disagree. At some point this was true but recent versions made a huge improvement. Now you can only say that it has a rather steep learning curve but once you get the hang of it you'll appreciate its scalability. Plus, it will seems really easy if you're familiar with the "Spring way".

Answer (score 26):

[Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) is a powerful and easy-to-use Java security framework that performs authentication, authorization, cryptography, and session management. With Shiro’s easy-to-understand API, you can quickly and easily secure any application – from the smallest mobile applications to the largest web and enterprise applications. :http://shiro.apache.org/

[jGuard](http://jguard.xwiki.com/xwiki/bin/view/Main/WebHome) is written in Java. Its goal is to provide a security framework based on [JAAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Authentication_and_Authorization_Service) (Java authentication and authorization security). This framework is written for web and standalone applications, to resolve simply, access control problems: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jguard/

The [Bouncy Castle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bouncy_Castle_%28cryptography%29), we believe in encryption. That's something that's near and dear to our hearts. We believe so strongly in encryption, that we've gone to the effort to provide something for everybody, and we've now been doing it for over 10 years: http://www.jasypt.org/

Comment: +1 for some names other than Spring Security.

Answer (score 13):

[Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org) is probably the most feature-rich open-source security framework for Java when you take into account not just authentication and authorization (which it does extremely well), but also things like robust clusterable (and container independent) sessions and its simplification of cryptography.

It also works in any Java application, not just Spring applications, but it has great Spring integration out of the box.  The documentation is really good and the API documentation is excellent by open-source standards.  The user community is also extremely helpful.

But probably better than anything else: it is super easy to understand and use.  Security APIs can be cumbersome and tricky to learn - Shiro probably has the cleanest and easiest to understand API out there.